# Создание игр для Android

Tags: android, ide

Я прочитал информацию про движки, но хотел бы узнать, в основном на чём создаются многие игры для Андроид (2d, 3d, логические и т.д), нельзя ли всё это создать в Eclipse, например?

Comment: В любой IDE с использованием подключаемых движков или на чистом Open GL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, например используя AndEngine:

> AndEngine это движок для написания 2D
> игр для Андроид. Движок бесплатный,
> производительный. Обладает большим
> набором функций: работа со спрайтами,
> встроенные элементы управления,
> экранные джойстики, модуль физики,
> поддержка работы со звуком, текстом,
> меню и пр.
>
> Автор Nicolas Gramlich. Страничка
> проекта в Google Игра от автора движка
> Farm Tower — 2d головоломка,
> использует в расчетах библиотеку
> физики.
>
> Документации на него практически нет,
> что характерно для многих бесплатных
> разработок. Способы работы с ним
> передаются из уст в уста либо на
> буржуйских форумах. Отсутствие
> документации компенсируется наличием
> множества простых примеров
> использования функций движка.
>
> Движок устанавливается на IDE Eclipce.

[Вот](http://alldream.org/android/programmirovanie/andengine-ustanovka/) пример установки.
[Вот](http://www.andengine.org/) оффициальный сайт.

Comment: ага спасибо))а как Unity?

Comment: Unity довольно мощный мультиплатформенный инструмент для разработки. Есть достаточное количество уроков, ночтоб писать под Андроид (30 дней бесплатно) но потом придется платить 400$ за стандартный пакет и 1500$ за Pro.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4g8h6s6Du7E
вот такую игрушку например не будет проблема создать с помошью AndEngine ?

Comment: Можно вместо AndEngine использовать libgdx. Имхо он технологичней и удобней.

Answer (score 3):

Основные движки - это AndEngine и libgdx. Оба 2d и оба бесплатные. Первый чуть более тормозной(как утверждают, сам не проверял). В использовании оба довольно просты.
Из платных можно выделить Unity 3d(есть под Android).

Вообще, введите запрос в гугле "android game engines" и получите массу информации.

Стоит добавить, что движки - это конечно здорово, но нужно знать мат.часть и OpenGL. Движки просто немного упрощают работу с OpenGL, реализуя частые в игростроении вещи. Но без основ что-то серьезно делать бессмысленно.

*А еще можно(и стоит) писать графическую часть на С++ с Android NDK(движок Cocos 2dx например используя) и тогда у вас будет кроссплатформенная часть, которую можно будет отдельно от платформы(ios, android, bada) пилить и быстро портировать на другие ОС.*

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы писать игры для Android, прежде всего надо хорошо знать язык Java. А в Eclipce не можно, а нужно работать. Только для этого в Eclipce нужно установить дополнение, называется Android SDK, ну и установить пакет расширения JDK ([Java Development kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html))

Comment: Если знать с/с++ тоже можно писать, только уже надо установить  Android NDK :)

Comment: Совершенно верно !!!

Comment: я это всё знаю,у меня просто не было опыта создании игр,я так понял нужно библиотеку движка подключить к еклипсу.

Comment: Если Вы про AndEngine, то да, необходимо поключить к Эклипсу (выше я дал ссылку).